# SQL Server - apply to case when to multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of columns that contain values between 0 and 4, like so:

```
ID      Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6   ...    Q30
0001    4     0     3     1     0     4           2
0002    0     2     1     2     0     3           1
0003    4     2     3     0     3     0           4
0004    1     4     2     4     1     1           3
```

I need to transform these values so that 4=0, 3-25, 2=50, 1=75 and 0=100.

So, in the transformed version my first row would show the following:

```
ID      Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6   ...    Q30
0001    0     100   25    75    100   0           50
```

If it was just for one column I would use a case statement:

```
case
  when Q1=4 then 0
  when Q1=3 then 25
  when Q1=2 then 50
  when Q1=1 then 75
  when Q1=0 then 100
end Q1
```

Can I apply this to a range of columns instead of doing a separate case statement for each column?

Or is there a more efficient way of achieving the same outcome?

Comment: No, you cannot apply case to multiple columns in one go. However, you may be able to simplify the transformation assuming the actual logic is exactly as shown in your sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write the condition like this
is more efficient,
because now is just an aritmetical operation,
and is better then a case with 5 check

```
SELECT 100 - (q1 * 25) AS Q1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update yourtable
set Q1 = 100 - Q1 * 25,
Q2 = 100 - Q2 * 25,
Q3 = 100 - Q3 * 25,
Q4 = 100 - Q4 * 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about functions, something like this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION COL_EVAL(@Q1 : int) RETURNS INT AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN case
  when @Q1=4 then 0
  when @Q1=3 then 25
  when @Q1=2 then 50
  when @Q1=1 then 75
  when @Q1=0 then 100
 end Q1
 END
```

And after all use it as:

```
 SELECT COL_EVAL(Q1) as Q1, COL_EVAL(Q2)....
```

p.s. have no server to check syntax correctness...